# why do i get not found 'symbolics' pkg on julia prompt> using Pkg and julia> Pkg.add("symbolics")

Tags: julia

I installed julia version 1.7.2 successfully, and Julia works fine with simple Julia program constructs.
To use 'symbolics' package, I read that I need to enter:

```
julia> using Pkg
```

=> this line executed with julia prompt

```
julia> Pkg.add("symbolics")
```

=> this line gives the following error:

```
symbolics (not found in project, manifest or registry)
```

I cannot follow this error, and I do not know how to add symbolics pakage to julia to use julia `symbolics.jl` package.

Comment: `symbolics` should be `Symbolics` probably?

Comment: This question is quite hard to read due to lack of formatting.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `Pkg.add("Symbolics")`, as mentioned in the package [installation instructions](https://github.com/JuliaSymbolics/Symbolics.jl/#installation).

As a rule, Julia packages start with a Capital letter, and generally follow the CamelCase convention.